# C++ placement new not compatible with boost allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, allocator

I'm using **Boost.Interprocess** shared memory, and I'm using interprocess Allocator with some STL compatible containers, when it comes to `placement new`, the code won't compile since `placement new` expect `void *` while `boost::interprocess::allocator::pointer` can't not be converted to `void *`.

below is a code to reproduce this

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;

typedef ipc::allocator<int, ipc::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;

int main() {
    struct shm_remove {
      shm_remove() { ipc::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      ~shm_remove() { ipc::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    } remover;
  ipc::managed_shared_memory segment(ipc::open_or_create, "MySharedMemory", 1024 * 1024 * 10);

  ShmemAllocator shm_alloc(segment.get_segment_manager());
  ShmemAllocator::pointer shm_ptr = shm_alloc.allocate(1);

  std::allocator<int> std_alloc;
  std::allocator<int>::pointer std_ptr = std_alloc.allocate(1);
  
  new(std_ptr) int(3);
  new(shm_ptr) int(3); // this line doesn't work

  return 0;
}
```

the compile error I got:

```
/home/ziqi.liu/ClionProjects/shared_memory_experiment/src/main_a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/ziqi.liu/ClionProjects/shared_memory_experiment/src/main_a.cpp:22:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator new(sizetype, boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >::pointer&)’
   new(shm_ptr) int(3); // this line doesn't work
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:63,
                 from /home/ziqi.liu/ClionProjects/shared_memory_experiment/src/main_a.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/new:111:7: note: candidate: void* operator new(std::size_t)
 void* operator new(std::size_t) _GLIBCXX_THROW (std::bad_alloc)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/new:111:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/new:119:7: note: candidate: void* operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
 void* operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/new:119:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >::pointer {aka boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<int, long int, long unsigned int, 0ul>}’ to ‘const std::nothrow_t&’
/usr/include/c++/5/new:129:14: note: candidate: void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)
 inline void* operator new(std::size_t, void* __p) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
              ^
/usr/include/c++/5/new:129:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >::pointer {aka boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<int, long int, long unsigned int, 0ul>}’ to ‘void*’
In file included from /home/ziqi.liu/.tspkg/include/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/detail/mem_algo_common.hpp:35:0,
                 from /home/ziqi.liu/.tspkg/include/boost/interprocess/allocators/detail/allocator_common.hpp:35,
                 from /home/ziqi.liu/.tspkg/include/boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp:30,
                 from /home/ziqi.liu/ClionProjects/shared_memory_experiment/src/main_a.cpp:2:
/home/ziqi.liu/.tspkg/include/boost/container/detail/placement_new.hpp:24:14: note: candidate: void* operator new(std::size_t, void*, boost_container_new_t)
 inline void *operator new(std::size_t, void *p, boost_container_new_t)
              ^
/home/ziqi.liu/.tspkg/include/boost/container/detail/placement_new.hpp:24:14: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
CMakeFiles/main_a.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main_a.dir/src/main_a.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_a.dir/src/main_a.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:162: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main_a.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_a.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm sure there must a way to do this, since boost own containers are all compatible with `boost::interprocess::allocator::pointer`, but I'm not sure how they did it......I guess I should look for an alternative for **placement new**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using an allocator in a container, the correct way to construct an object is to call

`std::allocator_traits<AllocatorType>::construct(alloc, pointer, ...constructor parameters...)`

See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) for more.

If you require a C++03 solution (no `allocator_traits` in C++03), then you can call the allocators `construct` method directly - but that's not the recommended solution.

Comment: This is not gonna fix the no-fancy-pointer allocators?

Comment: Note that `ipc::allocator::construct` takes an `ipc::allocator::pointer` as a parameter.

Comment: I'm aware of that (see [many answers]()) but it doesn't fix a lack of support in standard library containers, I think? The problem is (obviously?) not that allocator (that's part of the library), but using it with containers.

Comment: Reading the question again, I see how it appears to focus on the placement-new question rather than the narrative that probably lead to the question. So, +1 for a great targeted answer to that :)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the standard containers do not afford fancy pointers. See e.g.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator#Fancy_pointers:

  > An example of a fancy pointer is the mapping address-independent
  > pointer boost::interprocess::offset_ptr, which makes it possible to
  > allocate node-based data structures such as std::set in shared memory
  > and memory mapped files mapped in different addresses in every
  > process. Fancy pointers can be used independently of the allocator
  > that provided them, through the class template std::pointer_traits
  > (since C++11). The function std::to_address can be used to obtain a
  > raw pointer from a fancy pointer. (since C++20)
- https://quuxplusone.github.io/draft/fancy-pointers.html

My usual bet is to use Boost Container collections, because they *do* support these. And also, they seem to behave a lot better with scoped allocator adaptors than most standard library implementations in my experience.

Just to goof off a bit:

**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fb15d6c857da733)**

```
#include <boost/container/container_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc = boost::container;

template <typename T>
using Alloc = ipc::allocator<T, ipc::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>;
template <typename T>
using ScopedAlloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<Alloc<T> >;

template <typename T>
using SharedVector = bc::vector<T, Alloc<T> >;

template <typename K, typename V, typename Pair = std::pair<K const, V> >
using SharedMap = bc::map<K, V, std::less<>, ScopedAlloc<Pair> >;

int main() {
    ipc::managed_mapped_file segment(ipc::open_or_create, "MySharedMemory", 1024 * 100);
    auto* sm = segment.get_segment_manager();

    {
        auto &v = *segment.find_or_construct<SharedVector<int>>("vector")(sm);
        v.push_back(3);
        v.insert(v.begin(), 5);
        v.emplace_back(16);
    }

    {
        using String = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ScopedAlloc<char> >;
        auto &m = *segment.find_or_construct<SharedMap<String, String> >("map")(sm);

        m.emplace("whoa", "not bad");
        m.emplace("at", "all");
    }
}
```

Note I used a smaller size and `managed_mapped_file` because of limits on Coliru

Comment: thanks for the answer! I realized that STL containers are not compatible boost ipc allocator. The good news, as you mentioned, boost provide good alternatives for std containers. Currently, I'm having some third party library in my code and I'm trying to customize it to make it work with ipc allocator(specifically, I'm using https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash-c11, which provide much better performance compared to `std::unordered_map` in my usecase, and it seems that it already use the fancy `Alloc::pointer` type, the only issue is the`placement new`)

Comment: @ZiqiLiu in that case Marshall's answer is right on the money